Should I do the loop inside Task or directly in the accept procedure?
I'm trying to use the Websockets (not signalr) in .NET, and I found this article to be useful.
public class WSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWSChat);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    private async Task ProcessWSChat(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
        while (true)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(
                buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                    buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                userMessage = "You sent: " + userMessage + " at " + 
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userMessage));
                await socket.SendAsync(
                    buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

However, I'm confused in the handler function

Should I do the while (true) in the handler or return a Task? e.g return new Task(() => { ... })
I tried the second method and the loop is not executed. If I'm supposed to do the loop inside the handler, then why is this method uses Task as the return type?


I'd suggest using CancellationToken in your method, like this
private async Task ProcessWSChat(AspNetWebSocketContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
you should be able to access CT from your HttpContext context, under RequestAborted property.
And then your while condition can be changed into
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   ...
}

So this code will run until application or user somehow will decide to stop it (like will stop application or some other part of the code will escalate operation cancellation. Generally, that's a way to go with all async operations, cancellation tokens should go through entire call stack, from the very top level to the bottom :)
